# select & update query tremendously slow in MySQL Innodb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 1 table with 2.5 billion records(2.5 Cr.) and I am trying to get count of records based on indexed column. it takes 115 seconds to execute same.

Query

```
Select count(1) from table1 where column=code

Table1: table with 2 billion (2 Cr.)
code gets resultset from DB with 1 to 10k rows,
Column is indexed. 

Server Details
Intel Xeon 3.10ghz
8 gb RAM

MySQL server 5.1
MySQL Connector 5.0.6

My.cnf details
Default Engine =InnoDB
Innodn_buffer_pool=4G
```

Also take too much time for Update query please suggest how do i tune mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 Gbytes of ram for a 2 billion row table is not that much.

The `select` query presumably just has to read the index, but the index has to be loaded into memory.  This requires loading all 2 billion rows of the index into memory and then using it.  115 might seem a little on the long side, but not incredibly long.

You want to review your memory settings, to be sure you are using available memory.  You might consider getting better hardware for this size problem.  Alternatively, you might want to partition the table by code, if that is a common filtering clause.

Comment: Thank you very much...Partition would be better option for Select but what about  update ? please help..